# Using paper clip gem on heroku

Tags: heroku, paperclip

i have a model named post and i am trying to add a image content for post by using paper clip gem , i works fine when i run it local. But when i deploy it on heroku it throws an error **"image has contents that are not what they are reported to be"**

Post model is

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :comments
  has_many :ratings
  belongs_to :user

  #scope :recent, -> {where :user_id = 3)}

  scope :t , ->(from) { where("posts.created_at > ?", from) }
  scope :f , ->(from) { where("posts.created_at < ?", from) }
  #scope :created_before, ->(time) { where("created_at < ?", time) }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users , join_table: :posts_users_read_status
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  has_attached_file :image


  validates_presence_of :name, :presence => true,message: "Name should not be blank"
  validates_length_of :name,:maximum => 20,message: "Maximum 20 characters are allowed"
  validates_attachment :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: "image/jpeg"

  validates_attachment_size :image, :in => 0..1024.kilobytes
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

form for post is

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post],:html => {:class => "postsform",:multipart => true}, :remote => true  do |f| %>
            <% if @post.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this topic from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>

    <div class="images">
      <%= f.label :image %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :image,class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <div class=namefield">
    <%= f.label :Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
  </div>


   <div class="Tags">
    <%= f.label :Tags %><br>

        <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
            <div>
            <%= check_box_tag "post[tag_ids][]", tag.id, @post.tags.include?(tag) %>
            <%= tag.name %>
            </div>

  <% end %> 
</div>
    <%= link_to 'Create New Tags', tags_path %>
    <div class="actions">
      <div id="loading-indicator">
        <%= image_tag("\assets\images\ajax-loading.gif", :id => "loading-indicator", :style => "display:none") %>
      </div><%= f.button "Post", data: {disable_with:'<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>Posting in'} ,id:"postb"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

heroku logs

```
2016-01-06T04:33:01.991166+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename images_(3).jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, [#<MIME::Type:0x007f63421e07d8 @content_type="image/jpe
g", @raw_media_type="image", @raw_sub_type="jpeg", @simplified="image/jpeg", @media_type="image", @sub_type="jpeg", @extensions=["jpeg", "jpg", "jpe"], @encoding="base64", @system=ni
l, @registered=true, @url=["IANA", "RFC2045", "RFC2046"], @obsolete=nil, @docs=nil>] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this com
bination.
```